# Mariadb not running after AWS Linux 2 installation

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, mariadb

I'm running an AWS Linux 2 AMI and installed mariadb. The packages installed are:

[image: yum list | grep maria]

But when I try to start the service running

> sudo systemctl start mariadb

I get

> Failed to start mariadb.service: Unit not found.

Any hints?

Comment: I think the service is spelled "mysql", not "mariadb".

Comment: Tried that first and nope. Neither mysql nor mariadb show when running "sudo systemctl list-unit-files"

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Try a fresh Amazon Linux 2 instance.

Comment: In your listing, the only thing that's `installed` is `mariadb-libs`. All other packages are shown as availabl on the Amazon repository.

Comment: (also, in the future, please do not take a screenshot of a terminal window. Instead, copy/paste the actual text, using the code formatting option (looks like `{}`).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally it worked after explicitly running yum install mariadb-server

Comment: Always a good idea to install software before trying to use it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the service first, as it comes disabled:

```
systemctl enable mariadb
```

Then you can start it normally:

```
systemctl start mariadb
```

Comment: Doesn't work for mariadb nor mysql

Comment: What do you see when you try to enable mariadb?

Try "rpm -qf /usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service".

Do you get the following as result? "mariadb-server-5.5.62-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64"

If so, what's your partitioning scheme? Maybe you are hitting https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8307

Comment: I get "error: file /usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service: No such file or directory"